# How to get a specific thing from response (html) and save it as a variable (python)

Tags: python, html

Response (html) I get looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
--------------------
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function onClickButton(word) {
        if (word == 'yes'){
          var authorizationCode = '360ad5ce-ecfe-4ad4-83d1-9254e89a3ccc';
          var state = 'c8271b81-4229-6a1f-bf9c-758f11c1f5b1';
        } else {
          alert(word);
        }
      }
    </script>
    <div class="shb-psua-sign-app-sandbox-container">
    --------------------
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I get var authorizationCode value? and save it as a variable in python.
I'm doing an API request and the request looks like this:

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("xxxxxxxxx")

payload = "client_id="+Client_Id+"&grant_type=authorization_code&scope=AIS%3A"+consentId+"&code=xxxxx&redirect_uri=https://"

headers = {
    'Accept': "application/json",
    'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    'accept': "application/json"
    }

conn.request("POST", "/openbanking/redirect/oauth2/token/1.0", payload, headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

This just prints out the whole html.
I'm not sure what to do to just access the value...

Comment: Use a regular expression to extract the authorization code. The fact that it's HTML is irrelevant here.

Comment: You don't need both uppercase and mixed-case headers. Header names are case-insensitive.

Comment: The response you're getting isn't JSON, so `Accept: application/json` isn't correct.

Comment: I'm just using provided documentation for this API in sandbox/test environment. Don't really need to change anything as long as it works (for now). Will try regular expression now.

Comment: you can use regex or `start = find("var authorizationCode = '") + len("var authorizationCode = '")` and `end = find("';', start)` and later `code = data[start:end]`

Answer (score 1):

You have string so you can use string functions like `find()`, `split()`, etc.

```py
start = text.find("var authorizationCode = '") + len("var authorizationCode = '")
end   = text.find("';", start)

code = text[start:end]

print(code)
```

Or you can use `regex`

```py
results = re.search("var authorizationCode = '([^']*)'", text)

code = results.group(1)

print(code)
```

---

Full working example

```py
text = '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
--------------------
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function onClickButton(word) {
        if (word == 'yes'){
          var authorizationCode = '360ad5ce-ecfe-4ad4-83d1-9254e89a3ccc';
          var state = 'c8271b81-4229-6a1f-bf9c-758f11c1f5b1';
        } else {
          alert(word);
        }
      }
    </script>
    <div class="shb-psua-sign-app-sandbox-container">
    --------------------
    </div>
</body>
</html>'''

#text = data.decode('utf-8')

# --- version 1 ---

start = text.find("var authorizationCode = '") + len("var authorizationCode = '")
end   = text.find("';", start)

code = text[start:end]

print(code)

# --- version 2 ---

import re

results = re.search("var authorizationCode = '([^']*)'", text)

code = results.group(1)

print(code)
```